# Angular ui timepicker pop up not showing up

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap, timepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap-tab

The following code not showing up pop up timepicker. Any idea how to fix?

Code:

```html
<ul class="dropdown-menu custom-scroll dropDownLabel custom-width" role="menu" aria-labelledby="btn-append-to-body"
                    ng-show="!sr.timedisplay" 
                >
                    <li role="menuitem">
                        <a href="" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()">Start Time
                           
       <p class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" timepicker-popup ng-model="sr.startTime" is-open="opened" timepicker-options="timeOptions" ng-required="true"/>
         <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="sr.getTime('startTime')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i></button>
         </span>
        </p>
                        </a>
                    </li></ul>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This used to work:

```
<uib-timepicker></uib-timepicker>
```

Now you need to do this:

```
<div uib-timepicker></div>
```

Comment: the documentation is not that specific for the changes we get lost

Comment: I was seriously scratching my head over this one.  The change in directive definition causes the control to no longer appear on the page - everything just silently failed when I upgraded to a new version of angular-ui.  This fixed that issue for me.

Answer (score 6):

There is no such thing as a `timepicker-popup`, at least not in the official [**documentation**](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) - the question is tagged as [angular-ui-bootstrap](/questions/tagged/angular-ui-bootstrap)?

But you can create one by yourself using the `timepicker` and a `dropdown` :

```html
<span uib-dropdown auto-close="outsideClick">
  <a href uib-dropdown-toggle>
    {{ displayTime }}
  </a>
  <ul class="uib-dropdown-menu">
     <li>
        <uib-timepicker ng-model="mytime" hour-step="hstep" minute-step="mstep" show-meridian="ismeridian"></uib-timepicker>
     </li>
  </ul>
</span>
```

the script is basically the same as from the [**timepicker docs**](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/timepicker), besides a `displayTime` used for the dropdown :

```js
$scope.$watch('mytime', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    var hour = $scope.mytime.getHours()-($scope.mytime.getHours() >= 12 ? 12 : 0),
        hour = hour<10 ? '0'+hour : hour,
        minutes = ($scope.mytime.getMinutes()<10 ? '0' :'') + $scope.mytime.getMinutes(), 
        period = $scope.mytime.getHours() >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM';
    $scope.displayTime = hour+':'+minutes+' '+period
  })
```

plnkr -> **http://plnkr.co/edit/J4alKogyKuevSGdTkLFQ?p=preview**

**NB**: The plnkr is in 0.14.3. If you are using Angular UI Bootstrap prior to 0.14.0 then of course skip the `uib-` prefixes and it will work.

---

button style with glyph :

```
<span class="btn btn-default" uib-dropdown auto-close="outsideClick" >
  <a href uib-dropdown-toggle>
    {{ displayTime }} <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i>
  </a>  
  <ul class="uib-dropdown-menu">
     <li>
        <uib-timepicker ng-model="mytime" hour-step="hstep" minute-step="mstep" show-meridian="ismeridian"></uib-timepicker>
     </li>
  </ul>
</span>
```

**http://plnkr.co/edit/fyC6TfDsrJqsuGCqm11t?p=preview**

Comment: yep, thanks! That's what I just wanted to understand. But, I need timepicker to be opened once the form input group's icon is clicked.!

Comment: @Smitha, well - your example was a little bit confusing and clearly taken out of a larger context, it does not render to anything as it is, so I dont know what exactly you are heading for...  input-groups is for adding text, buttons or icons to input controls - but what do you want an input control for?  You could just add btn classes and the glyph to the span, see update.

Comment: @davidkonrad thanks for this, and for those who are using later versions of ui bootstrap, they now migrated the directive as an attribute not an element anymore, `<div uib-timepicker ng-model="mytime" ng-change="changed()" hour-step="hstep" minute-step="mstep" show-meridian="ismeridian"></div>` spending my time to figure this out

Comment: No where else, I found to drop off 'uib' for older version. Thanks, it worked. I think documentation no longer mentions about lot older version.. 

However, in my case, the drop down is getting closed as soon as I click on input box of time. I've tried every value of `auto-close` but doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

based David's sample/input, here is a sample with input component in html, but no controller.  And I tested it against Firefox and Chrome, it works well.  BTW, I am using bootstrap v3.3.6 and Angular UI bootstrap v1.3.2.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2" style="text-align: right">
        <label>Time Picker Popup</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control">
            <div class="input-group-btn" uib-dropdown auto-close="outsideClick">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" uib-dropdown-toggle><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i></button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" uib-dropdown-menu>
                    <li><uib-timepicker ng-model="mytime" hour-step="1" minute-step="15" show-meridian="false"></uib-timepicker>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```